Can't boot Windows as a side-OS in dual boot: error: can't find command drivemap error: invalid EFI file path
I am a yet another poor soul stuck with GRUB at dual boot.
The problem
When I select the option to boot Windows, grub throws the error
error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.

Also, it just worked randomly once today. I could boot into Win10  rebooted to Linux and it is stuck again. No idea what did I do so fundamentally diferent.
What I tried

Windows repair from the installation media - "The tool could not repair your computer"
boot-repair: it did not work from within my system and made me do this from a live USB. It did not do anything it seems (but unhiding the boot menu which also disappears randomly).
Adding the custom option to /etc/grub.d/40_custom as

menuentry "Windows 10 New" {
         insmod part_gpt
         insmod chain
         set root='(hd1,gpt1)'
         chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}

which I then replaced with
menuentry "Windows 10 New" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntldr
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    drivemap -s (hd0) (hd1)
    chainloader +1
}

each time I ran sudo update-grub and rebooted.
if it did anything then just the boot menu to disappear once...
boot-repair reports

Before the repair
After the repair

EFI settings

Safe boot disabled
Fast boot disabled
Compatibility mode enabled
Some other compatibility settings* have options "Legacy only" or "UEFI only", I set them to Legacy only

(*will update this shortly...)
Hardware
2 SSD Samsung drives (sda with Ubuntu, sdb with Windows; the Win boot partition is sdb1)

GRUB version 2.06
Motherboard: ASRock AB350M Pro4
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 1300X (4) @ 3.500GH
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/5

Is there maybe any bios setting I am missing?
Could it be caused by the way I mount/unmount the NTFS drives?
Small UPD
With the second snippet in the 40_custom file I have two additional lines of error:
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_msdod.mod' not found
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod' not found

"part_msdod" - really? There is a file "part_msdos.mod" indeed... looks like a typo to me?!

Windows is on a non-gpt disk, therefore it's a legacy install.  Looks like you tried an UEFI  Ubuntu install, and then started editing config files to further "correct" that error. Most cases have both Ubuntu and Windows in the same mode.

Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. Then I'll have to reinstall Ubuntu, I guess?..

A new install is frequently easier than cleanup of a bad one. The machine settings determine how the live media boots (unless you used a tool that forces one type of boot), so check those first and ensure legacy/csm (compatibility mode) is set. How the media boots is how it installs.

Strange then, I am pretty sure the compatibility mode was Enabled all along (this is also the default option in my case apparently)
